# i need to get Employees data , DB is Sql server , Sql server is located in Different place

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

My Requirement: i need to get Employees data , DB is Sql server , Sql server is located in Different place.

This is the approach i did : To connect sql server i Went with BCS solution , all i have given connection and i can able to access Table in the DB. i have created External content list and given connection is fine. when iam trying to open data in this url eg: "https://Naresh.sharepoint.com/sites/naresh/" iam get Error " Unable to render the data. If the problem persists, contact your web server administrator.

Note: all this work is done in office 365.

Comment: Any unusual about the data types being returned?

Comment: Have you checked this thread https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/e8714446-9d64-438c-a68a-693c1a57b2f8/sharepoint-online-unable-to-render-the-data-if-the-problem-persists-contact-your-web-server?forum=sharepointcustomization